# canceling double fractions how?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I had this example:
$$ \frac{\frac{11}{5}}{2} = \frac{11}{10} $$

then:

$$ \frac{2\frac{1}{5}}{2} = \frac{11}{10} $$

$$ \frac{1}{5}  \not= \frac{11}{10} $$

is this right canceling of double equation?

Comment: In this context, $2 \frac{1}{5} \neq 2 \times \frac{1}{5}$. If that were the case, i.e., if $2 \frac{1}{5} = 2 \times \frac{1}{5}$ then $\frac{2 \frac{1}{5}}{2} = \frac{1}{5}$. But it is not.

Comment: Note that the $2\frac{1}{5}$ actually represent $2+\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: thanks guys, didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always regarded the triple (or quadruple) fraction notation to be confusing and wrong, so instead (even to this day) I always make myself read fractions like this:

> The fraction $\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}$ is equivalent to $\frac{a}{b} \div c$ and therefore $\frac{a}{b} \times \frac{1}{c} = \frac{a}{bc}$.  For quadruples it works the same: $\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a}{b} \div \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{b} \times \frac{d}{c} = \frac{ad}{bc}$.

So using this I would say $\frac{\frac{11}{5}}{2} = \frac{11}{5} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{11}{10}$.

Comment: yeah I think the same, the are confusing :D

Answer (score 0):

$2\frac{1}{5}$ does not mean $2 \times \frac{1}{5}$. It means $2+\frac{1}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. Multiplying $$\frac{\frac{11}{5}}{2}$$ by $$\frac{5}{5}\ (=1)$$ gives you
$$\frac{\frac{11}{5}}{2}=\frac{\frac{11}{5}}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{5}=\frac{\frac{11}{5}\cdot 5}{2\cdot 5}=\frac{11}{10}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can think like this: $$\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{c}{d}}=\frac{a}{b}\times\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{c}{d}}=\dfrac{a}{b}\times\dfrac{d}{c}$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{11}{5}=2\frac{1}{5}$$ thus $$\frac{2\frac{1}{5}}{2}=1+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{11}{10}$$

Comment: so in this case 2 is multiplied by 1/5 right? if we are canceling them both?